# Android Bug - display area blocked - old UI fragments shining through current UI

Tags: android, user-interface

I don't know if this is the right place to ask for a solution.

I have a weird bug on Samsung S9 Android 8.0:

The area for the 3 Buttons (Menu, Home, Back) is blocked for some apps, so their UI ends on the top border of this area although I set these buttons to not fixed so that I have to swipe up to see them. One of these apps is Instagram.

Also, there is the problem that the outline of some UI is shining through the current UI of each app, no matter which app is currently running. This UI is always the same. I removed all UI elements from an app I'm working on so that I have a completely white screen. Then I made a video because on screenshots the UI fragments are not visible:

https://der-magere-student.com/public/media/WIN_20210115_02_29_04_Pro.mp4

On the bottom you can see:

1. In more or less black: the android menu buttons (BUT NOT THE REAL ONES, the real ones are hidden until I swipe up)
2. In more or less white: 4 of the five toolbar button of Instagram (home (house icon), the magnifying glass, the Plus (inside the android home button), and the heart) The fifth is not visible

On the top you can see:

1. The right side of the WhatsApp toolbar: From right to left. The more icon, the call icon, and the video call icon
2. horizontally centered with a bit offset from the top display border you maybe can see a little bar. I don't know where this comes from

There is a lot more but it's not visible on the video and also not identifiable for me. But I can see something.

Does anyone know where this bug comes from? Is it known? How to fix it?

Comment: Samsung may have whitelisted these apps... it may be considered a bug if you manage to reproduce it on stock Android, but not some (know to be problematic) vendor-specific ROM. And also, your question does not feature the least code to reproduce the issue and we're not clairvoyants on here.

Comment: It's definitely not a whitelist problem. I identified the bar I mentioned. It's the header of a table layout of an app I wrote myself. But this was more than a year ago. And I uninstalled this app over a year ago. But I only have this bug for about 2 months. If I would know how to reproduce it...

Comment: There is no code to reproduce. It just happened out of nowhere...

Answer (score 1):

You're looking at [OLED screen burn-in](https://www.cnet.com/how-to/oled-screen-burn-in-what-you-need-to-know-now/).  It's not a software problem; it's actually wear on the screen that happens slowly over time.

The UI you're seeing at the bottom of the screen is Android's navigation buttons, which are particularly notorious for getting burned into the screen (see, for instance, [this image](https://img.gadgethacks.com/img/35/26/63644433342425/0/understanding-oled-difference-between-lgs-poled-samsungs-amoled-screens.w1456.jpg) from [this article](https://android.gadgethacks.com/how-to/understanding-oled-difference-between-lgs-poled-samsungs-amoled-screens-0180699/)), because they're always in about the same spot.  Newer versions of Android take measures to reduce the burn-in from them, but there's only so much that it's possible to do.

Try opening something that shows a white screen with the navigation buttons hidden: you'll see the same thing.

Comment: If it's just a screen problem why do some apps do not fill up the screen and keep the affected area free?

Comment: @Kasko some apps want to leave the navigation buttons visible so that they can be easily pressed by the user.